# IE8 text-shadow issue with Google Font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a site http://test.printavo.com that renders terribly in IE8 but fine in IE7 and IE9.  I'm not sure if IE8 has different standards for some reason but the main issue is that the text-shadow for 'Open Sans' Google font looks terrible...

[image: ie8]

Anyone have a fix for this?  Maybe convert all fonts to Arial, I tried to text-shadow:none !important for IE but that didn't work (check out my source)

**EDIT:**
Is there a better way to take off all text-shadows in IE?

Comment: What does that look like in chrome/moz/opera?

Comment: IE lower than 10 does not support text-shadow.

Comment: @MaratTanalin and yet it seems to have a shadow. Confusing.

Comment: It looks great in all other browsers including IE7 and IE9. It seems the issue is with the Google Font.  Posted an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/06/29/full-css3-text-shadows-even-in-ie/

It would seem there are a variety of choices to choose from. The link above should give you some options. I should note they say IE8 can display text-shadow unpredictably and you should look the caveats section (link below) to try some fixes.

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/04/23/css-blurred-text-shadow-in-ie-part-i/#caveats

**EDIT**: 
In request to your browser specific css styling, you can target IE styling using conditional comments, just add this line to the >head< tags of your HTML file:

```
<!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mysite.com/path/to/ie9.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```